# Rules for file extensions?

Tags: windows, file

Are there any rules for file extensions? For example, I wrote some code which reads and writes a byte pattern that is only understood by that specific programm. I'm assuming my anti virus programm won't be too happy if I give it the name "pleasetrustme.exe"... Is it gerally allowed to use those extensions? And what about the lesser known ones, like ".arw"?

Comment: Not really, aside from avoiding colliding with other common extensions that you would expect to be handled by the operating system or other software you are free to use whatever you like (so long at it obeys the rules for allowed characters etc)

Comment: If your "specific program" knows how to read the byte pattern, you don't need(forced) to assign any known extension. You can just use, ".dat (generally used for data files)" or whatever you want. Or you can leave the file without any extension :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any file extension you want (or none at all). Using standard extensions that reflect the actual type of the file just makes things more convenient. On Windows, file extensions control stuff like how the files are displayed in Windows Explorer and what happens when you double click on it.

Answer (score 2):

> I wrote some code which reads and writes a byte pattern that is only
>   understood by that specific programm.

A file extension is only an *indication* of what type of data will be inside, never a guarantee that certain data formatted in a specific way will be inside the file.

For your own specific data structure it is of course always best to choose an extension that is not already in use for other file formats (or use a general extension like .dat or .bin maybe). This also has the advantage of being able to use an own icon without it being overwritten by other software using the same extension - or the other way around.

But maybe even more important when creating a custom (binary?) file format, is to provide a [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) as the first bytes of that file, maybe followed by a file header structure containing a version number etc. That way your own software can first check the header data to make sure it's the right type and version (for example: anyone could rename any file type to your extension, so your program needs to have a way to do some checks inside the file before reading the remaining data).